# Key translation

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

As a result of an answer in a previous question of mine I am trying to translate  `M-RET` in `C-u C-RET` using the following code:

`(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-RET") (kbd "C-u C-RET"))`

I have used the same code to translate other functions and it worked flawlessly so I don't know what is wrong with it. Does anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with using `key-translation-map` (I hope somebody else will chime in). My guess is that it makes Emacs look up the binding of `C-u C-RET`, not `C-RET` with a prefix argument.

This alternative seems to work, though:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-RET") (kbd "C-u C-<return>"))
```

Comment: Ok that works fine! Thank you. Let's wait for someone to explain why my solution didn't work...

Answer (score 9):

The [input translation maps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#Translation-Keymaps) (`input-decode-map`, `local-function-key-map`, `function-key-map`, `key-translation-map`) apply only within a key sequence. While you can specify multiple keys in the output of the translation, they'll only be counted towards binding.

For example, consider:

```
(define-key key-translation-map [f12] [?\C-x ?\C-f ?a])
(define-key key-translation-map [f11] [?\C-u C-return])
(define-key key-translation-map [f10] "abc")
```

<kbd>F12</kbd> is translated to `C-x C-f a`. The key sequence `C-x C-f` is bound to `find-file`, so pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> will invoke `find-file`, and the extra `a` input event will be discarded. Similarly, <kbd>F11</kbd> is translated to `C-u C-return`, which invokes `universal-argument` and discards the extraneous event `C-return`. Pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> invokes the command bound to `a`, which is `self-insert-command`; the character `c` is actually inserted, because `self-insert-command` inserts the character based on the last input event.

If you want `M-RET` to be equivalent to `C-u C-return` in all contexts where `M-RET` is not bound, then you can bind it in the global keymap. In keymaps other than the translation maps, if the binding for a key is an array of events (such as constructed by `kbd`) or a string, then the binding is interpreted as a sequence of events to replay — a macro. Note that `C-RET` isn't normally generated; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> is `C-return`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-RET") (kbd "C-u C-<return>"))
```

Given that `C-return` is not globally bound by default, it would probably make more sense to define `M-RET` in the mode where you want to use it. It would be clearer to bind `M-RET` to a function which does whatever you want — if `C-return` invokes `foo-frobnicate` then you might do something like

```
(defun foo-frobnicate-harder ()
  (interactive)
  (frobnicate t))
(define-key foo-mode-map (kbd "M-RET") 'foo-frobnicate-harder)
```

If you really want `M-RET` to be equivalent to `C-u C-return` in every context, you can stuff events into `unread-command-events` — see [Simulating mouse operations with keyboard](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/967/simulating-mouse-operations-with-keyboard/999#999) for an example.