# Update point using mouse

Tags: mouse, cursor, point, thing-at-point

I have been trying to add a custom keyboard command that will find a functions definition using `S-mouse1`.

The issue is that I need two mouse clicks for this to work.  The first click is to move cursor to the function who's definition I want to find. The second click is the `S-mouse-1` to trigger the function to find it's definition.

Here is what I have added to my `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-mouse-1>")
            (lambda ()
              (interactive)
              (xref-find-definitions (thing-at-point 'word))))
```

An ideal solution would update point based on my mouse position and then use `thing-at-point` to pass the symbol into `xref-find-definitions`

I tried adding the following solution to my config without success: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30856/21056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
(lambda (event)
  (interactive (list last-command-event))
  (posn-set-point (event-end event))
  (xref-find-definitions (thing-at-point 'word)))
```

In the case of mouse events, the event contains data about where the event took place, so you can use it to move point where the click happened.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Relatively new to elisp, so this helps a ton.

I can't find much documentation on some of these functions.

I found a little bit about `last-command-event` here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Loop-Info.html

And have not been able to any real documentation about `posn-set-point` other than this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36088695

Do you have any recommended resources for learning more about built in functions like these and elisp in general?

Comment: @Priceatronic: My recommendation is to look at other functions doing the same kinds of things.