# Keyboard equivalent of left mouse click in org mode

Tags: org-mode, mouse

Is there a keyboard equivalent of left mouse click in emacs?

Use case here is an .org file I have which contains a no. of URLs

I can left click on those URLs to have them open in a browser

I was wondering whether there was a combination of key presses that would achieve the same, so I don't have to reach for the mouse?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/967/simulating-mouse-operations-with-keyboard

Comment: The accepted answer below is simpler and specific to org mode, so slightly different to the linked duplicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function `org-open-at-point` (bound to `C-c C-o`) does precisely that I think.  Its docstring (obtained through `M-x describe-function`) includes:

> (org-open-at-point &optional ARG REFERENCE-BUFFER)
>
> Open link, timestamp, footnote or tags at point.
>
> When point is on a link, follow it.  Normally, files will be
>   opened by an appropriate application.  If the optional prefix
>   argument ARG is non-nil, Emacs will visit the file.  With
>   a double prefix argument, try to open outside of Emacs, in the
>   application the system uses for this file type.
>
> ...

Additionnaly, as mentionned by @Nick, the return key can be used instead of `C-c C-o` if variable `org-return-follows-link` is non-nil:

> org-return-follows-link is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means on links RET will follow the link.
>   In tables, the special behavior of RET has precedence.

Comment: you are absolutely correct! I've just tested and it works as expected, i.e. link opens as new tab in browser - I'll modify the OP to reflect that its specific to org mode..

Comment: See also the variable `org-return-follows-link`. If you set it to `t`, then `RET` follows the link (but not if the link is in a table).