# The C-x C-j binding for dired-jump stopped working

Tags: dired, key-bindings

I used to have a keyboard shortcut for the following action:

> "Open the folder containing this file in Dired+, and place point (cursor) on the file"

I believe it was `C-x C-j`, and I don't recall setting it up manually. It seems to be gone. Did recent changes to Dired+ perhaps change this?

Either way, are there any Dired or Dired+ built-in interactive functions that I could use for this? If not, how can I go about building one?

I can run `M-x dired-jump`. The problem seems to be that the keybinding is gone.
When I do `C-h k C-x C-j RET`, I see `C-x C-j RET (translated from C-x C-j <return>) is undefined`.

Comment: Do you use jabber?

Comment: @Malabarba I do actually have Jabber installed (but am not directly loading it in Emacs directly). Could it still be the problem? I will check.

Comment: jabber binds C-x C-j as a prefix. It might be getting loaded without you realising. Try uninstalling (just move it to a different directory, you can move it back later).

Comment: @Malabarba That was it. Good to know! If you write that as an answer I will of course accept it.

Comment: FWIW: Library [dired+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/dired%2b.el) does not change `dired-jump` or any key binding to it. `dired-jump` is not even mentioned in **Dired+**.

Comment: In a case like this ("X stopped working"): (1) Try to repro from `emacs -Q`. (2) If you can't repro from `emacs -Q` then recursively bisect your init file, to see which part is causing the problem. To do that, comment-out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8... You can use `comment-region` to do that (`C-u` uncomments). After trying all of that, if you need more help (and you probably won't), ask here.

Comment: @Drew: +1 for "and you probably won't". :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Problem

`jabber.el` and `dired-x` unfortunately conflict on this keybind.
Jabber uses `C-x C-j` as the prefix for all its keys, while dired
sets it to your beloved `dired-jump` (that’s probably why the latter
is made optional through the `dired-bind-jump` variable).

Do complicate things further, if Jabber is installed with `package.el`
it binds this key twice! First on Emacs startup, then upon loading
`jabber.el`.

### The Solution

Bind `dired-jump` both before and after Jabber has been loaded. Make
sure this happens after `(package-initialize)` in your init file
(if you use it).

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") #'dired-jump)
(eval-after-load 'jabber-keymap
  '(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") #'dired-jump))
```

Or, if you’re using Emacs 24.4, the following is slightly preferred:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") #'dired-jump)
(with-eval-after-load 'jabber-keymap
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") #'dired-jump))
```

To continue using the jabber keymap, you can bind it to a different key sequence, as in

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") jabber-global-keymap)
```

Comment: What does the `#` before `'dired-jump` signify? I've also seen it being used when adding functions to hooks.

Comment: @kaushalmodi It's a `function` quote. It’s almost the same as a regular quote, but it tells the byte-compiler this symbol is a function (which it can use to give useful warnings). It’s irrelevant in your init-file, but it’s relevant in packages so I try to motivate good practice.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already noted, you're thinking of the function `dired-jump`, which is provided by Dired-x (not Dired+), and is bound to `C-x C-j` when the Dired-x library is loaded. (You can turn off this binding by setting `dired-bind-jump` to `nil` before Dired-x is loaded.)

Given that `C-x C-j` does something, rather than complaining that `C-x C-j` is undefined, what's happening is that something else has defined a binding for it. Whoever defined the binding last wins.

So you need to track down what other package that you're loading is overriding `C-x C-j`. That package is loaded after Dired-x, so if you're loading `dired-x` in your init file, it's either something that you're loading further on or something that gets autoloaded at some point.

Since `C-x C-j` doesn't do anything on its own, but waits for another key to be pressed, it's a prefix key. Press `C-x C-j C-h` to see a list of bindings that start with this prefix. This should give you a good idea of the culprit package.
[Malabarba's hypothesis](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/open-the-folder-containing-this-file-in-dired-and-place-point-on-the-file#comment2697_2150) that it's Jabber mode is a plausible one. Once you've identified a key sequence that starts with the prefix `C-x C-j`, press `C-h k` followed by that key sequence. This will show the help text for that command and the package that provides the command. It's likely that the package that provides the command is the same package that defines the binding.

It's unlikely that you'll need to go that far, but just in case, if there's some key binding you can't track down, see [How can I find out in which keymap a key is bound?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-i-find-out-in-which-keymap-a-key-is-bound/654#654)

If you want to load that package that overrides `C-x C-j`, but you don't want it to take over that binding, see if it has an option to skip that binding. If it doesn't, you can snatch the binding back: arrange to run `(global-set-key "\C-x\C-j" 'dired-jump)` after the offending package is loaded. It may be enough to put that at the end of your init file. If not, you can use

```
(eval-after-load "NAME-OF-THE-OFFENDING-PACKAGE" '(global-set-key "\C-x\C-j" 'dired-jump))
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you see when you do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>?

You should see that it is bound to `dired-jump`. If it's not then you either haven't done `require` of `dired-x` or you/some other package overrode that binding with something else.

If you can do `M-x dired-jump` and just need that binding, then you can do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") 'dired-jump)
```

But if `dired-bind-jump` is `t` and if you have `(require 'dired-x)`, then that package will set that binding for you.

Comment: Thanks - I see `C-x C-j RET (translated from C-x C-j <return>)` is undefined.

Comment: Can you do `M-x dired-jump`? If not, then you don't have the `dired-x` package loaded.

Comment: Thanks @kaushalmodi -- Yes I can do `M-x dired-jump`. Forgot to mention that in the OP

Comment: Given that the command is there and the problem is that my bindings are messed up, perhaps I am better off asking this in a different question "How can I debug a missing keyboard binding?" or similar?

Comment: That binding should work as expected if you launch `emacs -Q` and do just `(require 'dired-x)`. If that works, then gradually populate your `init.el` till that binding goes away once again; that way you'll find the culprit. Another way is doing recursive grep/ag/ack for `C\-x\s+C\-j` in your .emacs.d folder.

Comment: The question has been answered, but the first comment here is telling -- the fact that the `RET`/`<return>` was listed in the key sequence (which was not expected) indicates that `C-x C-j` is a *prefix* binding for something. You could therefore use `C-x C-j C-h` to find out which bindings *are* available under that prefix, which would undoubtedly point to the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I use this regularly.  Just tested it with `emacs -Q`, this is all you need:

```
(require 'dired-x)
```

The functionality is provided by `dired-x`, which is different from `dired+`.  The former is shipped with core Emacs, the latter is a 3rd party extension library.

Comment: Also ensure that `dired-bind-jump` is set to its default value `t`.

Comment: Thanks @legoscia I just checked and `dired-bind-jump` is `t`. I am also loading `(require 'dired-x)`. Strange

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any offending packages i.e. no packages took over the binding `C-x C-j` but still this shortcut, which was working on a different Emacs session, stopped working i.e. a new Emacs session didn't have this bound.

I realized that in the session where this binding was working, I'd earlier launched `dired` manually (using `M-x`) and then on this key combination was bound; I used it subsequently mistaking it as a binding that's always there.  While on the newer Emacs session, I hadn't launched `dired` or `dired-x` till that point, so the key combination wasn't bound; it wasn't working.  The solution is to manually bind it so that it works irrespective of whether `dired` was launched or not.

[Dired Extra has a section in its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/dired-x.html#Optional-Installation-Dired-Jump) on this which cleared it up for me.

> In order to have dired-jump and dired-jump-other-window work *before* `dired` and `dired-x` have been properly loaded you should set-up an autoload for these functions.  In your `.emacs` file put

```
     (autoload 'dired-jump "dired-x"
       "Jump to Dired buffer corresponding to current buffer." t)
     
     (autoload 'dired-jump-other-window "dired-x"
       "Like \\[dired-jump] (dired-jump) but in other window." t)
     
     (define-key global-map "\C-x\C-j" 'dired-jump)
     (define-key global-map "\C-x4\C-j" 'dired-jump-other-window)
```