# How can I open 'dired' mode from any buffer by ONE hotkey?

Tags: dired

I am using Windows 10 and Emacs 26.1.

Suppose I open some file:

[image]

And now I want fast open *dired* mode. The result must be like this:

[image]

I want to do this by ONE hotkey direct from a buffer. E.g. `C-x j`.
Is it possible?

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2150/105.

Comment: Are you asking about how to use a different key from `C-x C-j` (e.g. `C-x j`, as you wrote)?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dired-jump` from the builtin `dired-x.el`. I have it bound to <kbd>C-x C-j</kbd>, you can setup your own key binding.

> `C-x C-j` runs the command `dired-jump` (found in global-map), which is an
>   interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `dired-x.el`.
>
> It is bound to C-x C-j.
>
> (dired-jump &optional OTHER-WINDOW FILE-NAME)
>
> Jump to Dired buffer corresponding to current buffer. **If in a file,
>   Dired the current directory and move to file's line.** If in Dired
>   already, pop up a level and goto old directory's line. In case the
>   proper Dired file line cannot be found, refresh the dired buffer and
>   try again. 
>   When OTHER-WINDOW is non-nil, jump to Dired buffer in other
>   window. When FILE-NAME is non-nil, jump to its line in Dired.
>   Interactively with prefix argument, read FILE-NAME.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. But presumably the OP already knows about `dired-jump`, as he posted [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/44498/105) about it a couple weeks ago.