# html-mode and custom backspace keybinding

Tags: keymap

I changed the `C-h` key binding to be used as backspace.

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-h") (kbd "< DEL >"))
```

Now, this works flawlessy pretty much everywhere except in `html-mode`. When I'm in an HTML command minibuffer and press <kbd>C-h</kbd>, instead of deleting the last character this message appears:

> You are inserting a skeleton.  Standard text gets inserted into the buffer
>   automatically, and you are prompted to fill in the variable parts.

How could I solve this problem if possible?

Comment: Ahh I see, I missed the part about the minibuffer. I'm really not sure what mode is overshadowing your map.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I find out in which keymap a key is bound?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/653/50)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an interesting one.

`html-mode` is derived from `sgml-mode`, which uses [skeletons](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Using-Skeletons.html), which may read input from the minibuffer, which, underneath it all, uses `read-char` to get keyboard input.

[`read-char`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-One-Event.html#index-read_002dchar-1434) gets one event (one key press) *before* the `key-translation-map` is used. On top of that, if the `help-form` (`minibuffer-help-form` when reading from the minibuffer) variable is bound and is not `nil`, characters equal to `help-char` are captured and trigger the evaluation of `help-form` (or `minibuffer-help-form`), the value of which, if it is a string, is displayed in the `*Char Help*` buffer.

Here's the problem: `C-h` is the default value of `help-char`. This makes it impossible to input `C-h` (or whatever `help-char` is set to) if `minibuffer-help-form` is set, and `skeleton-read` *does* set it.

This suggests that the issue described in the question should affect other modes too.

Here's a minimal example:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-h") (kbd "<DEL>"))

(let ((minibuffer-help-form "Help!"))
  (read-from-minibuffer "Try using ^H now! "))
```

To get around this, you can just

```
(setq help-char nil)
```

or customize this variable. This disables evaluation of `help-form` and `minibuffer-help-form` everywhere.

Alternatively, you can add advice to `skeleton-read` to allow using `C-h` in skeleton prompts and keep the default behavior elsewhere:

```
(advice-add 'skeleton-read :around
            (lambda (orig &rest args)
              (let ((help-char nil))
                (apply orig args))))
```