# Helm: override C-h

Tags: key-bindings, helm

I followed [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/358/219) answer and created my minor mode to avoid my keybindings being overridden by any major modes.

So I put this in my init.el:

```
(define-key my-keys-mode-map (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
(define-key my-keys-mode-map (kbd "M-h") 'backward-kill-word)
```

It is working with everything except when I am in `helm-find-files`. While `M-h` works, `C-h` doesn't. If I press it twice, `Help` buffer shows up saying:

```
^L
Major Mode Bindings Starting With C-h:
key             binding
---             -------

C-h C-b     helm-send-bug-report-from-helm

^L
Global Bindings Starting With C-h:
key             binding
---             -------
```

How can I disable `C-h` in `helm-find-files` and keep using my own keybinding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C-h` is special: see [my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3814/2355) to [html-mode and custom backspace keybinding](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3787/2355).

In short: whenever you rebind `C-h` you should also change the value of [`help-char`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Help-Functions.html).

To disable its action, do

```
(setq help-char nil)
```

(You can also set it to a different character.)

In addition to this, `helm-find-files` uses `C-h` as a prefix key. The code below replaces the `C-h` prefix with `M-m`, which should free `C-h` up to be used as "backspace":

```
(eval-after-load "helm-files"
  '(let ((helm-find-files-C-h-map (lookup-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-h"))))
     ;; make sure C-h is no longer a prefix key
     (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-h") nil)
     ;; rebind "C-h ..." to "M-m ..." to preserve functionality
     (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "M-m") helm-find-files-C-h-map)))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Now ```C-h``` does nothing and ```C-h C-h``` shows ```C-h C-h is undefined```

Comment: @Boccaperta-IT: I updated the answer; please give it another try.

Comment: Adding the code prompts an error upon startup: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function keymap)
  (keymap (keymap (2 . helm-send-bug-report-from-helm)) keymap (109 . helm-help) (104 . undefined) (8 . undefined) (4 . helm-debug-output))
  (lambda nil (keymap (keymap (2 . helm-send-bug-report-from-helm)) keymap (109 . helm-help) (104 . undefined) (8 . undefined) (4 . helm-debug-output)))()

Comment: Using ```(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-h") nil)``` works. There is no need to use ```(setq help-char nil)```. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Boccaperta-IT: I think I fixed the code in the answer (needed to quote the let-form). As for setting `help-char`, you don't need it to make helm work, but you *may* need it for other Emacs features (such as skeletons) to work (see the question I linked to).