# Why does C-c C-x look like an empty keymap?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I'm trying to find which map `C-c C-x` is bound to on my system, but `C-c C-x C-h` reveals *nothing*.  `(describe-key (kbd "C-c C-x"))` reports that the sequence is unbound, yet I can still type `C-c C-x` and Emacs awaits more input (as if it were waiting for another key in the sequence).

What's going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out in which keymap a key is bound?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-i-find-out-in-which-keymap-a-key-is-bound)

Comment: @Gilles problem is that it's an empty keymap.

Comment: Empty? How can it be empty if it maps your key?

Comment: @T.Verron Beats me.  Try it out in `emacs -Q`; the behavior persists for me (homebrewed emacs 24.4)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Stefan figured out the issue.  The two questions I pose in the original question are unrelated, so I'm just going to focus on the one :) (The X–Y problem at work…)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, interactively `C-h k` can't be used if you're trying to find where a prefix map is defined.  And even the question itself may be somewhat meaningless in the sense that it can be defined at various places at the same time (Typically the `C-c` prefix is bound to a keymap which is a dynamically-computed combination of various keymaps, e.g. from the major-mode and from various minor modes).

But you can still do

```
M-: (describe-key [?\C-c ?\C-x]) RET
```

which should tell you (in a recent enough Emacs, and in the case where all bindings in this prefix come from a single keymap) which keymap defines this prefix.

Note that `C-c C-x` might wait for more input as if it were a prefix even if it isn't.  This is because determining "the end of a key-sequence" is quite tricky: while there's no binding for C-c C-x maybe what you're trying to see is if there's a binding for C-c é and you're doing that by hitting C-c C-x 8 ' e, so after the C-x Emacs keeps waiting for more input to figure out what's going on.

Another way to investigate key prefixes is with `C-h`, so you'd do `C-c C-x C-h` and it should show you the bindings available in `C-c C-x`.  Sadly in this case it only shows you the "normal" bindings and not the key-remapping bindings, so it won't explain why Emacs is waiting.  This probably deserves a feature request via `M-x report-emacs-bug`, so that `C-c C-x C-h` shows that it can be followed by `8 ' e` and things like that.