# Binding <ESC> <ESC> to have <ESC> <ESC> <ESC> functionality

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys, escape

I'm not a fan of hitting escape 3 times so I am trying to have the same functionality with two key presses.

I have tried the following:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<ESC> <ESC>") 'keyboard-escape-quit)
```

This doesn't work and it actually seems to break the normal `<ESC> <ESC> <ESC>` functionality as well.

Any Ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just do `(global-set-key (kbd "<ESC> <ESC>") 'keyboard-escape-quit)`?

Comment: M-ESC ESC  is what I have by default from emacs

Comment: @JeanPierre has the correct solution, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This binding is in the global keymap. Generally key bindings that work in most or all buffers are in the global keymap. If in doubt, see [How can I find out in which keymap a key is bound?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-i-find-out-in-which-keymap-a-key-is-bound) to check.

So you can simply call

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<ESC> <ESC>") 'keyboard-escape-quit)
```

This overrides the previous binding of `ESC ESC` as a prefix. Note that if some package subsequently tries to set up a binding with `ESC ESC` as a prefix, this will signal an error; but this is not a commonly used prefix so you should be fine.

If you use Emacs in Unix-style terminals, this will break the use of <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>function key</kbd> to encode <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>function key</kbd> (or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>function key</kbd> in Emacs tradition), because function keys are encoded as character sequences that start with `ESC`. This is the reason why Emacs defines `ESC ESC ESC` rather than `ESC ESC` as a default binding. If that doesn't mean anything to you, forget I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Press `C-g` instead. It is shorter and works everywhere.

Comment: This is not exactly the same thing https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html#Quitting