# How to use describe-key in Helm results buffer?

Tags: key-bindings, helm, minibuffer

While in the results buffer of `helm-projectile-grep`, I know I can use `C-<up>` and `C-<down>` to visit the files with the matches, but I would like to rebind those keys.

Normally I would use `C-h k` to run `describe-key` on the `C-<up>` sequence, then use the function name in `global-set-key`.

But typing `C-h k` in the results buffer (which I'm assuming in Helm's case is an expanded minibuffer, not sure about the terminology) only appends `k` to the search string, ignoring the `C-h`.

So how do I find out which function a key sequence is bound to in that situation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Helm, but I think it doesn't use a minibuffer, or if it does it uses a non-standard keymap, so a generic minibuffer answer is not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm redefines a lot of standard key bindings, including the ones to get help (which I find extremely rude).

A workaround is to add a binding for help on a key that Helm doesn't rebind, at least while you're investigating, for example:

```
(global-set-key [C-f1] 'help-command)
```

Then use `C-f1 k` in the context where you want to identify a key.

It may be more useful to directly ask Emacs where the key is bound. `describe-key` does this in Emacs 25. If you're using an older version, see [How can I find out in which keymap a key is bound?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-i-find-out-in-which-keymap-a-key-is-bound/654#654) — bind a key to Malabarba `locate-key-binding`, use it while in Helm, and later go and see the result in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: I tried `(global-set-key [C-f1] 'help-command)`, but it had the same effect as `C-h k`: the `C-h` / `C-f1` part gets ignored, and the `k` gets appended to the search pattern. 

Using Malabarba's `locate-key-binding` (taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisbarrett/spacemacs-layers/master/cb-core/local/locate-key-binding/locate-key-binding.el)) and looking at `*Messages*` gave me `helm-follow-action-forward` and `helm-follow-action-backward` which is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can issue a command (such as `C-h k`) that uses the minibuffer from the minibuffer itself only if you set **`enable-recursive-minibuffers`** to non-`nil`.

But most likely what you really want here is to get help on a *minibuffer keymap*. For that, use **`C-h M-k`** (`describe-keymap`) from library [**`help-fns+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el).

There are a few minibuffer keymaps. You might need to check more than one with `C-h M-k`, depending on which ones are being used for what you are interested in.

See the Elisp manual, nodes [Completion Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Completion-Commands.html) and [Text from Minibuffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-from-Minibuffer.html) for descriptions of the minibuffer keymap variables.

For example, you might try `C-h M-k minibuffer-local-keymap`.

On the other hand, if Helm uses its own keymaps in the minibuffer then you might need to enter the name of one of those when prompted by `C-h M-k`.

Keep in mind also that a minor-mode keymap overrides the predefined minibuffer keymaps, which are local maps.

---

If you used [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) (but Helm and Icicles are probably incompatible) then you can see which keys are available anytime, in any given context, including in the minibuffer.

- If the minibuffer is active then **`M-S-TAB`** at any point shows you the *key completions*. If no prefix key has been pressed yet then it shows you the top-level key bindings available in the minibuffer at that time.  The ***key = command*** bindings are shown as completion candidates in buffer `*Completions*`.  You can filter them by key name or command name or both.  And keys that are bound locally (i.e., in a local keymap) are highlighted specially.
- If the minibuffer is *not* active then **`S-TAB`** gives you the same behavior: it shows the available key completions at any time.

See [Icicles - Key Completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion).

Comment: You've answered the title question, but the question was really about Helm, and I think your answer doesn't apply to Helm, because as you suspect Helm has its own keymaps.

Comment: @Gilles: I expected that someone might offer a Helm-specific answer. But I also understood the question as being about keys in the minibuffer - as was asked. You've edited it to a quite different question now - perhaps more accurate, perhaps not. Yet you've still left the tag `minibuffer`! Is this about keys (bound in what buffer? what mode?) that act on a results buffer? Is it about keys bound in a minibuffer? Is a minibuffer active at the time? Is it about keys in a results buffer, or is about keys in another buffer that have an effect on a results buffer (a la an effect on `*Completions*`?

Comment: I only edited the title to match the body. I *think* that the minibuffer is active when browsing the results of `helm-projectile-grep` (even though a lot of the action happens in another buffer, in the same style as `*Completions*`). But since Helm rebinds `C-h` and `f1`, the standard ways to get help are not available. Even `M-x` doesn't work if it's helmified, which it is in the recommended Helm configuration; `M-:` does work if you don't helmify it and you enable recursive minibuffers.

Comment: I hadn't been able to use `describe-keymap` to test your answer because of a random helm/spacemacs [bug](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9549), but now that I fixed it, I was also able to run the command, describe the `helm-map` keymap and find the `C-up` / `C-down` bindings, so thank you!